# Monitor traffic through a home router

Tags: networking, router, monitoring

We have an Internet connection which is shared on five computers via a home router.

One of the computers is using [torrents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29#Creating_and_publishing_torrents) all the time. I want to find out which, and they won't tell me.

How can I check which client is using the most traffic?

Comment: Which operating system? Do you _know_ that it is specifically torrents? How are they connected (if via cable, you could just look at which corresponding connection LED flashes the most)? Which router model?

Comment: All operating systems are Windows 7. Some of them are downloading torrents most of the time. They are all connected via WiFi. Router is SpeedTouch THOMSON ST780.

Comment: Good answer that works independently of the router model, but unfortunately only for Ethernet traffic (not wifi traffic going directly to the router): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45042

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading these articles from [HTG](http://www.howtogeek.com/):

- [HTG: Capturing packets with wireshark](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/)
- [HTG: Monitoring bandwidth usage](http://www.howtogeek.com/67691/what-you-said-do-you-monitor-your-bandwidth-usage/)

Comment: What do they say about link-only answers?

Answer (score 1):

[WallWatcher](http://www.wallwatcher.com/) collects, displays, and analyzes log information from more than 135 Routers and firewalls.

Take a look at [Cacti](http://cacti.net/) as well.

Comment: WallWatcher does not support my router. Cacti requires MySQL, PHP, RRDTool, net-snmp, and a webserver that supports PHP such as Apache or IIS. So both are not good for me.

Comment: Wallwatcher also has generic IPTables and Syslog settings. If your router runs on Linux, you should be able to make it work.

Comment: wallwatcher.com says: Wallwatcher is no longer available. (since 2011)