# Check URL's that used by client of my private WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, sniffing

I have in my home internet with an access point with WIFI. Sometimes I see that my speed is really getting down. is theres a way I can listen to MY OWN network and to see the address that were entered by others computers through my my WIFI?

Answer (score 1):

Its not as simple as you are trying to put it, but the answer is **yes**.

You cannot "*listen to the network and see the addresses that were entered by other computers*". But you could potentially monitor all active connections made through the router and resolve source and destination IPs.

One approach is to use the packet analyzer like [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).

Another method is to implement logging within the router itself. Most routers with stock firmware from manufacturers don't have that functionality. Custom firmware like [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) or [OpenWRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) would allow you to implement that functionality. This would require some basic knowledge about networking and unix shell scripting.

UPDATE:

I just realized there is already a [thread](https://superuser.com/q/420426/281154) that covers the subject